# ¿Por que no se llama la funcion onRemoteMessagge de FCM cuando la app esta segundo plano?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-messaging

En mi aplicacon la funcion onremoteMessage no se llama cuando esta en segundo plano, envio desde mi servidor datos y mensaje de la notificación, solo se ejecuta en cuando la aplicacion esta abierta y ejecutándose.
Lo probesin optimizacion de bateria,y sigue igual,
tambien lo reince con invalidate cache y no cambia.
A continuación muestro el codigo:
Manifest

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/logo_mediano" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
   <service
        android:name=".mackey.FCMService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="false"

        android:resource="@drawable/ic_menu_camera">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    </aplication>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

clase del servicio

```
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "android-fcm";

    public FCMService() {
    }
   @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
     sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        System.out.println("remote message");
     
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Notificacion");
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
             Log.d(LOGTAG, "DATOS");
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Titulo: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Imagen: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("image"));
           
        }
    }
```

graddle Module App

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
```

Logcat en segundo plano:

```
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
I/FirebaseMessaging: Starting download of: https://image.freepik.com/imagen-coche-blanco_53876-12108.jpg
W/FirebaseMessaging: Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Logcat en primer Plano:

```
I/System.out: remote message
D/android-fcm: Notificacion
D/android-fcm: Notificatcion de Prueba
D/android-fcm: DATOS
D/android-fcm: Titulo : datos de php
D/android-fcm: Imagen : imagen
```

Comment: Hola, podrias agregar un ejemplo del JSON que estas enviando? es notification+data o solo data?

Comment: notificación+data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

según la [documentación oficial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=es), cuando tu app recibe una notificación con data mientras está en seguindo plano, el data se enregará en los extras del intent. Esto quiere decir que el data estará disponible en el activity que se abre cuando el usuario toca la notificación.

Puedes obtener los datos en tu activity de la siguiente forma:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        Bundle data=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(data!=null){
            //Aqui puedes obtener tus datos
            String dato1=data.getString("nombre de tu string");
        }
    }
```

Si necesitas que la información se entregue exclusivamente en el callback onMessageReceived, puedes omitir el objeto "notification", y envar todos los datos en el objeto "data", de esa forma tendrás que desplegar manualmente tus noificaciones, pero obtendrás el comportamiento que esperas.